# Problem with embed RCL in asp.net core with form

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I made an RCL(Razor Class Library) for reusable UI.

Here is the code of front-end:

```
@model Sample.Models.VistorModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
            <form id="ContactForm" asp-action="Contact">            
                <div>
                    <h3>@Localizer["Name"]</h3>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="Name" placeholder="@Localizer["NameHint"]" />
                <div>
                    <h3>@Localizer["Phone"]</h3>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Phone"></span>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="Phone" placeholder="@Localizer["PhoneHint"]" type="tel" />
                <button type="submit">@Localizer["Sumit"]</button>
            </form>
```

Here is the model:

```
public class VistorModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Sample.Resources.Views.Contact.Contact))]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhoneError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Sample.Resources.Views.Contact.Contact))]
        [RegularExpression(@"((\d{11})|^((\d{7,8})|(\d{4}|\d{3})-(\d{7,8})|(\d{4}|\d{3})-(\d{7,8})-(\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})|(\d{7,8})-(\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1}))$)", ErrorMessageResourceName = "NotAPhoneNumber", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Sample.Resources.Views.Contact.Contact))]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample.Controllers
{
    [Route("{culture}/[controller]")]
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Contact.html")]
        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("Contact.html")]
        public IActionResult Contact(Models.VistorModel Vistor)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

For example,
the RCL URL is `www.sample.com/contact/contact.html`
the page URL is `www.sample.com/home/index.html`(the page is made by asp.net core also)

Now I embedded the RCL into the page.

However, when I click the submit button on the page, the page will redirect to the `www.sample.com/contact/contact.html` but not `www.sample.com/home/index.html`.

Besides, I need to embed this RCL not only on the home page but also on any other page.

In a word, what I want to do is:
1.When I input nothing(invalid), the page will redirect to `www.sample.com/home/index.html` and show the invalid error message on the span which has set attribute `asp-validation-for` before.
2.When I input name and phone(valid), the page will redirect to `www.sample.com/home/index.html` and show a message box alert that submits success.

Now I don't know how to make the URL redirect and display the invalid error message correctly. How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you have set the asp-action, it will generate the form action with /contact/contact not home index.

To solve this issue, you should firstly move the RCL's view to the shared folder and then modify the form tag as below:

```
    <form id="ContactForm" method="post">
```

Comment: No, the RCL is not embedded in all the pages while only some of the them. And also, if I remove the asp-action, the model validation ErrorMessage will not work.

Comment: But if you don't remove it, it will always post to the contract action instead of go to the parent page's controller.

Comment: Em...Is there any way to achieve redirect and work with the model validation ErrorMessage?